# What database uses phonegap storage?

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, native, web-sql

I want to develop an native app with phonegap. I want to store my data in a sqlite database (size more than 5 mb). My question now is:

Do I have to use a native sqlite plugin for phonegap? In the docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
it says under "open database" it creates a new sqlite database. So why do I need a native sqlite plugin? This really confuses me because at the top of the page it says something about the websql standard which is deprecated.

What is phonegap storage api using? sqlite or websql ? and which limitation does it have?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think plugin is required for those device don't support WebSQL. WebSQL is supported in iOS, BB and Android browsers, but not in Windows phone or BB10. The plugin will polyfill, when WebSQL is not supported.

Alternatively, you can try my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home This is pure javascript, so you don't need plugin. The library support WebSQL and IndexedDB so should work for *most* platforms.

Comment: its good. But i want to access sqlite db from my java code . is it possible ?